# LookupAccountName fails on vista with ERROR_NONE_MAPPED

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-vista

I'm trying to call LookupAccountName on Vista - it always fails with the error ERROR_NONE_MAPPED.

What could be the reason??

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you give exact arguments that you pass to this function?

Answer (score 2):

ERROR_NONE_MAPPED typeically means that the username you provided is not available in the format you specified.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The user exists, and the format is correct. This problem occurs only on Vista, in other OSs it works excellent, so I think that it is not the problem. Any other idea?

Comment: Clearly, the user does not actually exist, or at least not in the format you specified it in, otherwise you would not be getting that particular error code.  Something else to consider is that LookupAccountSid() returns ERROR_NONE_MAPPED if a name for the SID cannot be found, which either means no name actually exists, or a network timeout prevented the name from being discovered.  A similar restriction likely exists in LookupAccountName() as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling UAC on the your machine. It should work after that.

Comment: The point is to make the code to work on any machine, not to force all users to change their machines.